# How to insert a bookmark only if the following command is completed

Tags: conditionals, bookmarks

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{bookmark}

\newcommand*\ifpdfexists[1]{%
  \IfFileExists{#1.pdf}{\includepdf[pages={-},fitpaper=true]{#1}\cleardoublepage}{\relax}}

\begin{document}

\pdfbookmark[1]{BookmarkName}{BookmarkName}%only create bookmark if the following file is found

\ifpdfexists{filename}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wrap it in the same `\IfFileExists` conditional to test whether the file exists or not... Since you're already using `\IfFileExists` in `\ifpdfexists`, I don't understand why you haven't tried this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
\newcommand*\ifpdfexists[2][Bookmark]{%
  \IfFileExists{#2.pdf}{%
    \clearpage
    \pdfbookmark[1]{#1}{#1}%
    \includepdf[pages={-},fitpaper=true]{#2}\cleardoublepage}{\relax}}
```

which incorporates the bookmark as part of the file/PDF inclusion. The optional argument to `\ifpdfexists[<opt>]{<file>}` represents the bookmark title. That can change though, depending on the interface preferences you desire.